# Counting tokenized words in data frame with pandas ( python)

Tags: python, tokenize

I have created a tokenized data ( text ) within a data frame in Python

I just want to count the tokenized data and have an output that shows the frequency of repetition for each element in the tokenized data.

here is the code I used to create the tokenized data :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re

def tokenize(txt):
    tokens = re.split('\W+', txt)
    return tokens

Complains['clean_text_tokenized'] = Complains['clean text'].apply(lambda x: tokenize(x.lower()))

# Complains['clean text'] is the original file of the data


Complains['clean_text_tokenized'].head(10)
```

here is the output of the tokenized data

```
0                   [comcast, cable, internet, speeds]
1     [payment, disappear, service, got, disconnected]
2                                [speed, and, service]
3    [comcast, imposed, a, new, usage, cap, of, 300...
4    [comcast, not, working, and, no, service, to, ...
5    [isp, charging, for, arbitrary, data, limits, ...
6    [throttling, service, and, unreasonable, data,...
7    [comcast, refuses, to, help, troubleshoot, and...
8                         [comcast, extended, outages]
9    [comcast, raising, prices, and, not, being, av...
Name: clean_text_tokenized, dtype: object
```

any advice would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Counter`:

```py
from collections import Counter
# ... and then
def tokenize(txt):
    return Counter(re.split('\W+', txt))
```

See a Python test:

```py
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd
import re

Complains = pd.DataFrame({'clean text':['comcast, cable, internet, speeds', 'payment, disappear, service, got, disconnected']})

Complains['clean_text_tokenized'] = Complains['clean text'].str.findall(r'\w+')

freq = Counter([item for sublist in Complains['clean_text_tokenized'].to_list() for item in sublist])
```

Comment: thank you for your help, I have tried the test and it went well. However, when I tried to do the same for all tokens I got an error message that says ( AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split' ) . Here is the code I used

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd
import re

def tokenized(txt):
    freq = Counter([token for item in Complains['clean_text_tokenized_without_stopwords'].to_list() for token in item.split()])
    return freq

Complains['clean_text_tokenized_without_stopwords'].apply(lambda x: tokenized(x))
````

Comment: @Hattan That just means you have a list rather than a string in the column. Make sure you only have strings in that column, and that means you need to check all your code before this one.